# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to access wp-admin url

Tags: php, wordpress, server, shared-hosting

I was launching a new Wordpress website under the domain name: `www.example.com`

When I try to access the cpanel or the wp-admin url it gives me this error message:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
>   contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@subdomain.example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error. More information about this error may be
>   available in the server error log. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server
>   Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to
>   handle the request.

Comment: With a new wordpress install, a 500 error right off the bat is often a sign of an .htaccess file that isn't set up properly. I'd start there.

Comment: Check your error logs, doing so will tell you what the issue is.

Comment: This is what the .htaccess file says: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Information/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Information/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Information/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Information/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score -1):

Please check your file permissions. You should set it to `755`, and your issue should be solved.

Comment: When you have enough reputation you can comment. Don't write comments as answers